# Accessing list from one method in another

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, list, methods

Im wondering how to access a list from one method in another. Basically i want to do something like this:

```
    public class StatisticsController : BaseNopController
    {

        public List<Visitors> CreateVisitorsReport (StatisticsListModel model)
        {
           var StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
           var EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

          // -- Visitors class contain properties "Date" and "TotalVisitors". Dates between Start and EndDate

           List<Visitors> VisitorsList = new List<Visitors>();

          //  --- Some code populating a list of Visitors objects


           return VisitorsList;

        }



    public List<Orders> CreateOrdersReport (StatisticsListModel model)
    {
       var StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
       var EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

       // -- Visitors class contain properties "Date" and "TotalOrders". Dates between Start and EndDate

       List<Orders> PersonList = new List<Orders>();

       //  --- Some code populating a list of Orders objects


       return OrdersList;

    }
}
```

Now in the third method i want to calculate the conversion rate with Visitors.TotalVisitors and Orders.TotalOrders, in order to do this would i will also need the reults from the returns of both "CreateVisitorsReport and CreateOrdersReport.

Sorry if my code looks stupid but i'm kinda new at this so this may not be optimal, i probably should use some pattern for this.

My third method would look something like this:

```
public List<IEnumerable> CreateConversionReport(StatisticsListModel model)
{

  List<Ienumerable> ConversionList = new List<IEnumerable>();

  foreach (var CreationDate in orders )
  {
  // -- Devide all Visitors in VisitorsList with Orders in OrdersList
  }

  return ConversionList;

}
```

Summary: in order to create the conversion calculation in "CreateConversionReport" i need to access     VisitorsList and OrdersList as they contain all data i need to calculate the conversion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 approaches,

1. declare 2 List variable in your class and assign them in methods(instead of return or after calling them) them use it in 3rd method
2. declare List and pass it to the  CreateOrdersReport and CreateVisitorsReport  and they fill the list
3. Call them in third method and you have the result of them then use it

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Call `CreateVisitorsReport`  and `CreateOrdersReport` from your method and get the lists, perform the operation.
2. If that is not what you want declare your lists in the class level, put the definition outside of your methods, then you can access them from `CreateConversionReport`.

Comment: Well my first thought was option 1 but i'm considering if option 2 might look better, what do you think? Also when you say "declare your lists in the class level" you mean as a list-property or simply a list?